# Python : How to load column from multiblock csv tables?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, block

I'm working on a fit program for SIP data right now. Unfortunately the data comes within a csv table with the following structure :

```
       f;      Abs(Zm);     Std(Abs);      Phi(Zm);     Std(Phi);       Re(Zm);       Im(Zm);     Time [s]
1.0000000e-001;    7712.6262;       0.0247;    -0.003774;     0.000001;    7712.5713;     -29.1074;   3418623040
2.0000000e-001;    7712.4351;       0.0030;    -0.007543;     0.000001;    7712.2157;     -58.1732;   3418623056
5.0000000e-001;    7710.8455;       0.0094;    -0.018837;     0.000002;    7709.4775;    -145.2434;   3418623063
1.0000000e+000;    7705.3763;       0.0098;    -0.037637;     0.000000;    7699.9195;    -289.9395;   3418623067
2.0000000e+000;    7683.8120;       0.0241;    -0.075058;     0.000001;    7662.1778;    -576.1935;   3418623069
5.0000000e+000;    7539.7945;       0.0080;    -0.184724;     0.000002;    7411.5201;   -1384.8720;   3418623071
1.0000000e+001;    7088.6894;       0.0060;    -0.351521;     0.000001;    6655.2169;   -2440.8206;   3418623072


         f;     Abs(Z12);     Phi(Z12);     Abs(Z34);     Phi(Z34);     Abs(Z14);     Phi(Z14);     Time [s]
1.0000000e-001;       1.7821;     3.139014;       0.2545;    -3.141592;    7710.5896;    -0.003774;   3418623040
2.0000000e-001;       1.7850;     3.133381;       0.2572;    -3.126220;    7710.3930;    -0.007543;   3418623056
5.0000000e-001;       1.7755;     3.121223;       0.2514;    -3.133763;    7708.8186;    -0.018838;   3418623063
1.0000000e+000;       1.7683;     3.100815;       0.2503;     3.139466;    7703.3580;    -0.037638;   3418623067
2.0000000e+000;       1.8091;     3.058834;       0.2538;    -3.123705;    7681.7502;    -0.075060;   3418623069
5.0000000e+000;       1.5547;     2.943611;       0.2398;    -3.136317;    7538.0045;    -0.184727;   3418623071
```

I'm using a numpy.loadtxt() routine to collect the data from the table like this :

```
def load_datafile(filename):
try:
     x_data, y_data = numpy.loadtxt(filename , unpack=True, usecols=(0,1),) 
except IOError:
    print('There was an error opening the file: {0}'.format(filename))
    x_data=[]
    y_data=[]
return x_data, y_data
```

I know there is no further identifier for using a specific block from a table in the loadtxt() command. But is there a handy workaround?

Otherwise is there a simple script which can do the rearranging of the csv-input file to single block colums?

Thanks in advance!
Greets,
Gunnar

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a "block"?

Comment: your example data has different columns in every block and the block size is different from block to block (7 rows in the first, 6 in the second). Is that true? Do you need to read the data from every block and every column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first split the input data into blocks, then use loadtxt or genfromtxt (I prefer this one, because it has an option to read headers).

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from StringIO import StringIO

def read_by_block(filename):
    blocks = []
    data = open(filename).read()
    for blk in data.split('\n\n'): # we assume that blocks are separated by two newlines
        blocks.append(genfromtxt(StringIO(blk), delimiter=';', names=True))
    return blocks

data = read_by_block('data.txt')

print data[0].dtype.names # print fields for first block
print data[0]['StdPhi'] # print column 'Std(Phi)' in 1st block
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of genfromtxt(). After manipulating the newline style in my csv table it worked great.

Comment: If you want more flexibility with respect to newline style, you can also split based on regular expression: `re.split`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming like the input there is always a pair of empty newlines, this little script should return a bunch of file objects:

```
def parseMultiblockCSV(filename):
    original = open(filename, "r")
    newlines = 0
    block = 0
    current = open(filename + "." + str(block), "w")
    for line in original:
        if line == "":
            newlines += 1
        if newlines >= 2:
            current.close()
            block += 1
            current = open(filename + "." + str(block), "w")
        current.write(line)
    current.close()
    files = []
    for n in range(block + 1):
        files.append(open(filename + "." + str(n)))
    return files
```

If you then needed them both in the same table I assume it has a function to load multiple files in to a single table. Otherwise:

```
def combineCSVFiles(files, output):
    if len(files) == 1:
        return files[0]
    start = file[0]
    files = file[1:]
    out = open(output, "w")
    for line in start:
        out.write(line)
    for input in files:
        first = false
        for line in input:
        if not first:
            first = true
            continue
        out.write(line)
    out.close()
    return open(output, "r")
```

That should return a file object containing the concatenated contents of the given file objects, ignoring the first header line of anything but the first file.

Comment: I think the columns are different from block to block, so your answer do no not handle that. Or do I miss something?